# group by scatterplot super impose regression line and rsq

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a dataframe and I would like to plot subplots for each universe in my data

I do the following which produces the scatterplots fine. The output is a scatterplot for each universe where csk is on the y axis and msk is on the x axis. I am trying to superimpose a regression line on each subplot and add the Rsq on each subplot. Is there a way to do this? is seaborn better to use ("regplot")

```
plt.suptitle(mytitle, fontsize = 20)
for (universe, group), ax in zip(temp1.groupby([temp1.universe], sort = False), axes.flatten()):
    group.plot(x='msk', y='csk', kind='scatter', ax=ax, title=universe,s=2)
    ax.set_xlim(0,1)
    ax.set_ylim(0,1)
    ax.set_xlabel("msk", fontsize =10)
    ax.set_ylabel("csk", fontsize = 10)
    ax.set_title(universe, fontsize = 12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fitting a regression line can be done quite simply with [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) or [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html#scipy.stats.linregress).

With the output from those functions, you can easily plot the regression with `matplotlib`'s [`ax.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) function.

Calculate `R^2` from your data and fit (look up the equation if you don't know it, its quite simple), and then add it to the plot with [`ax.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html) or [`ax.text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html)